# Getting items related to selected foreign key in django

Tags: django, admin

I'm building a django app that has customers model and projects model and tasks model. in tasks model I can select the customer name and project but the problem is that in admin panel it shows all the projects, is there any way to show projects only for the selected customer

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from suppliers.models import Currency
from users.models import Profile

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    customer_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    customer_phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    customer_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    notes = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer_first_name) + ' ' + str(self.customer_last_name)

class Account(models.Model):
    max_discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2)
    credit_limit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sales_man = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Agent = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    reason = models.TextField()


class TaskPriority(models.Model):
    priority_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    task_priority_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.task_priority_name)

class Project(models.Model):
    project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    customer_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    notes = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.project_name)


class Task(models.Model):
    task_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    customer_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    task_priority = models.ForeignKey(TaskPriority, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='projects_files')
    notes = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.task_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TabularInline to create project tab on customer record view in admin panel.

For example:

```
class ProjectInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Project
    extra = 1
    verbose_name = 'Project'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Projects'
    list_display = ...
```

And in Customer Admin model add

```
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = (ProjectInline, )
```